# Swift: UITextField resignFirstReponder() error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

this is my code, that drives me crazy:

```
lazy var currentEdit: UITextField! = nil
...

func cancelClicked() {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
    let setupButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Bearbeiten", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DetailViewController.toggleEditing))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =  setupButton
    if !self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !self.textChanged { // self.textChanged is false
        self.toggleEditing()
        return
...

func toggleEditing() {
    if !self.isValid {
        return
    }

    if self.currentEdit != nil {
        self.currentEdit.resignFirstResponder()  // the error is thrown HERE
    }
```

i get the error

> 2016-05-28 23:04:39.606 Visitenkarten[3695:121134] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

i don´t know why! :-( What means [__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

This is the content of some variables:
[image]

Do u have any idea, what i can do/check?

Must i add more Informations?

Comment: I'd look around the debugger stack to make sure that some other piece of code isn't actually failing, because that shouldn't cause that.

Comment: @sschale there´s nothing, i think... and i don´t know, what else can i show in debugger :-( I updated the question with more code.

Comment: You are implementing UITextFieldDelegate?

Comment: If you are implementing UITextFieldDelegate then maybe your problem is on optional public func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField), hope this helps

Comment: @Reinier Melian yes, u are right and when i remove the textFieldDidEndEditing(), everything is ok. :-) Now i  know the reason, THX a lot

Comment: @Reinier Melian found it: in textFieldDidEndEditing() i tried to enable a non-existing  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems![1]. <grrr>